# How to use Array and print all values on MPLAB C Compiler?

Tags: c

I am using MPLAB C18 Compiler with PIC18. My problem is that I can't print all the values even though this code works 100% on CodeBlocks. I spent more than 3 hours Googling this problem and I don't understand what's causing it. This is how the output looks like on both compilers.

**MPLAB OUTPUT**

> 2

**CODEBLOCKS OUTPUT**

> 2
>
> 100
>
> 200
>
> 100

**Code**

```
char somestr[] ="2,0100,0200,0100";
char *pt;
int a;
pt = strtok (somestr,",");

while (pt != NULL) 
{
    a = atoi(pt);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    pt = strtok (NULL, ",");
}
```

Comment: Try using `strcpypgm2ram` instead.

Comment: Did you include **stdlib.h** and **string.h**? Because otherwise, [your code seems to be just fine](http://ideone.com/sgFXQz).

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 , so what would be the line of code I am adding and am I removing the 'a = atoi(pt);' ?

Comment: @AnishRam, I have it included.

Comment: Before `pt = strtok(somestr,",");` you should have `strcpypgm2ram(pt, somestr);`, but I don't know if this will work or not.

Comment: @GRAYgoose124, it didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you post your entire code? This code snippet is definitely not the problem then.

Comment: What other suggestions to try out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses, I really do appropriate it. I found the solution and would like to share it. Instead of **strtok** I used **strtokpgmram**.

**Final Code**

```
char somestr[] ="2,0100,0200,0100";
char *pt;
int a;
pt = strtokpgmram (somestr,",");

while (pt != NULL) 
{
    a = atoi(pt);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    pt = strtokpgmram(NULL, ",");
}
```